# How to add Boost header files in Yocto?

Tags: linux, boost, header-files, yocto, bitbake

I added IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost" to my local.conf file but I can not seem to find the boost header files anywhere on my system. How do I install the header files for boost on Yocto?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have boost development headers and libraries in your image on target then you also need to add the devel package to your image

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost boost-dev"
```

However, if you are looking for the header on your build system where you are building yocto then you will have to add boost to dependencies of a package you are building, e.g. say you were building foo.bb then in foo.bb you will add

`DEPENDS += "boost"`

this will then ensure that boost libraries and headers are staged inside the build area of foo package.

Answer (score 0):

To add header Boost header files to your SDK you need to add boost-dev to TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " boost-dev"
```

You can do that in local.conf for example.

IMAGE_INSTALL will just add lib files to your target. There could be .so. files in your sdk, but that is not enough to build application for your target.